# How to write APNs server side code in scala?

Tags: scala, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I'm stuck at a very annoying problem.

I'm working with javaPNS and following one of the many guides on internet.

Here: https://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/PushNotificationAdvanced

```
 /* Push your custom payload */ 
    List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, devices);
```

where you see this, above. It says that Push.payload() returns a List with PushedNotificaion.
Well, it doesn't in my code.

```
object Push {

def devPush(pushAlertMessage: String, badgeNumber: Int, devices: Seq[String]): List[PushedNotification] = {

//Retrieve the .p12 certification file
val keystoreFile = getClass.getResourceAsStream("keystorefile.p12")

//Create payload
val payload = PushNotificationPayload.complex()
payload.addBadge(badgeNumber)
payload.addAlert(pushAlertMessage)
payload.addSound("default")

//
val notifications:List[PushedNotification] = javapns.Push.payload(payload, keystoreFile, keystorePassword, false, devices)

for(notification <- javapns.Push.alert(pushAlertMessage, keystoreFile, keystorePassword, false, devices).getFailedNotifications){
    /* Add code here to remove invalid tokens from database */
}

notifications
}
}
```

When I try to put a list in my val notifications with Push.payload it says:

"Express of type PushedNotifications doesn't conform to expected type List[PushedNotification]"

I'm tired and confused, not certain about the rest of the code either. Would appreciate any help and please. Correct my code if I'm wrong.

Comment: just wrap your value of type PushedNotifications into List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an implicit conversion from the `java.util.List` returned and the scala `List` that you want.  Try adding the following import:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

And tweak this line:

```
val notifications:List[PushedNotification] = javapns.Push.payload(payload, keystoreFile, keystorePassword, false, devices)
```

To this:

```
val notifications:List[PushedNotification] = javapns.Push.payload(payload, keystoreFile, keystorePassword, false, devices).toList
```

Also, it looks like you will be pushing two times to each device here as the calls to `payload` and `alert` both push notifications to the devices.  If you only really wanted to send the complex payload that you build, then your code should probably be:

```
val results = javapns.Push.payload(payload, keystoreFile, keystorePassword, false, devices)

for(notification <- result.getFailedNotifications.toList){
    /* Add code here to remove invalid tokens from database */
}
```

Comment: Great, just what was looking for! Thanks @cmbaxter. Do you see if there is any other issues in my code? I don't have the possibility to test it right now :(

Comment: Ofcourse, thanks for you answer. I see now that my code wasn't logic at all. I don't want to push twice :)